# Managing animation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uianimation

I am creating an iOS app. I need to show a splash screen with animation when the user open the app. Also i need to go to the next page of the app automatically after animation finished. How is it possible to go to next page of the app directly after animation finished. I am working with objective C.I have written code for the animation.Please help me.Thank you. Following function is used for my aniamtion.

```
  CABasicAnimation *animation =
[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[animation setDuration:0.05];
[animation setRepeatCount:8];
[animation setAutoreverses:YES];
[animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                         CGPointMake([_image1 center].x - 20.0f, [_image1 center].y)]];
[animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                       CGPointMake([_image1 center].x + 20.0f, [_image1 center].y)]];
[[_image1 layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

Comment: Please show us, what you have tried yet

Comment: try this https://github.com/sachinkesiraju/SKSplashView

Comment: I have just created a vibarating type animation over an image.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this Sample code link:- https://github.com/jaysonlane/OpenBook

Hope it will help you to animate Splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

After Launch image. You can make your animated splash screen.

```
[[_image1 layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

// After add this line

```
[[_image1 layer] removeAnimationForKey:@"opacity"];
```

Move to next view controller